# How to cut initrd made with update-initramfs command on debian12?

Tags: debian

Executing `update-initramfs -c -k 6.4.0-rt8`, it was found that the generated initrd was very large, with 470M, to the point where after restarting, it displayed: `error: out of memory`. How can I solve this problem?

I want to delete some files extracted by initrd and recompress them, but I don't know which files to delete?

Decompressed file information:

```
debian12@gyz:~/initrd/temp/test$ sudo unmkinitramfs initrd.img-6.4.0-rt8 .
debian12@gyz:~/initrd/temp/test$ ls
early  main initrd.img-6.4.0-rt8
debian12@gyz:~/initrd/temp/test$ ls main/
bin  conf  etc  init  lib  lib32  lib64  libx32  run  sbin  scripts  usr  var
debian12@gyz:~/initrd/temp/test$ ls early/
kernel
debian12@gyz:~/initrd/temp/test$
```

Is the method of recompression correct?

```
find . | cpio -H newc -o > ../new_initrd
gzip -9 ../new_initrd
mv ../new_initrd.gz ../new_initrd
```

cat /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf

```
#
# initramfs.conf
# Configuration file for mkinitramfs(8). See initramfs.conf(5).
#
# Note that configuration options from this file can be overridden
# by config files in the /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d directory.

#
# MODULES: [ most | netboot | dep | list ]
#
# most - Add most filesystem and all harddrive drivers.
#
# dep - Try and guess which modules to load.
#
# netboot - Add the base modules, network modules, but skip block devices.
#
# list - Only include modules from the 'additional modules' list
#

MODULES=most

#
# BUSYBOX: [ y | n | auto ]
#
# Use busybox shell and utilities.  If set to n, klibc utilities will be used.
# If set to auto (or unset), busybox will be used if installed and klibc will
# be used otherwise.
#

BUSYBOX=auto

#
# KEYMAP: [ y | n ]
#
# Load a keymap during the initramfs stage.
#

KEYMAP=n

#
# COMPRESS: [ gzip | bzip2 | lz4 | lzma | lzop | xz | zstd ]
#

COMPRESS=zstd

#
# COMPRESSLEVEL: ...
#
# Set a compression level for the compressor.
# Defaults vary by compressor.
#
# Valid values are:
# 1 -  9 for gzip|bzip2|lzma|lzop
# 0 -  9 for  lz4|xz
# 0 - 19 for zstd
#
# COMPRESSLEVEL=3

#
# DEVICE: ...
#
# Specify a specific network interface, like eth0
# Overridden by optional ip= or BOOTIF= bootarg
#

DEVICE=

#
# NFSROOT: [ auto | HOST:MOUNT ]
#

NFSROOT=auto

#
# RUNSIZE: ...
#
# The size of the /run tmpfs mount point, like 256M or 10%
# Overridden by optional initramfs.runsize= bootarg
#

RUNSIZE=10%

#
# FSTYPE: ...
#
# The filesystem type(s) to support, or "auto" to use the current root
# filesystem type
#

FSTYPE=auto
```

add `du -sch /etc/initramfs-tools/` :

```
debian12@gyz:~/initrd/temp$ du -sch /etc/initramfs-tools/
72K     /etc/initramfs-tools/
72K     总计
```

add `du -h`

```
debian12@gyz:~/initrd/temp/test$ find . -type f -size +20M -exec du -h {} +
44M     ./main/usr/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/kernel/fs/xfs/xfs.ko
35M     ./main/usr/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/kernel/fs/btrfs/btrfs.ko
30M     ./main/usr/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ice/ice.ko
29M     ./main/usr/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/netronome/nfp/nfp.ko
90M     ./main/usr/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/mellanox/mlx5/core/mlx5_core.ko
354M    ./main/usr/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu.ko
135M    ./main/usr/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
51M     ./main/usr/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon.ko
192M    ./main/usr/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nouveau.ko

debian12@gyz:~/initrd/temp/test$ ls initrd.img-6.4.0-rt8  -ltr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 483166934  8月29日 19:55 initrd.img-6.4.0-rt8
```

Comment: What’s your `MODULES` setting in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`?

Comment: @StephenKitt I added this configuration file, `MODULES=most`?

Comment: Please add the output of `du -sch /etc/initramfs-tools/` to your question.  It's definitely not normal for `update-initramfs` to generate 470MB initrd files (47MB, yes, 470MB no).  The only cause I can think of is that you've copied or sym-linked something huge into /etc/initramfs-tools (or maybe /lib/modules/kernel-version or some other dir used by update-initramfs).

Comment: @cas I have added it.

Comment: 72K is fine.  what was actually in the initrd when you unpacked it? try running `du -h` in the directory you unpacked it in - are there any files or dirs taking up hundreds of MBs of space?     One thing just occurred to me - did you misread a number like 47000000 as 470MB when it's really 47MB? If that's the case, examine any custom scripts you've installed into /etc/initramfs-tools to make sure they're not running some kind of inifinite loop that uses all RAM.

Comment: BTW, at what point, exactly, did it display the out of memory error? as soon as grub tried to load the initrd? or after it had loaded and was running?

Comment: #1. After replacing the Linux kernel from 6.1.0 to 6.4.0 and restarting, the initrd was generated without doing anything. I added the information 'du - h' to my question.
#2.as soon as grub tried to load the initrd.

Comment: After setting `MODES` to `dep`, the generated init has become 70M. `out of memory error` problem disappears.

Comment: ok, something's up with the size of the kernel modules for at least amdgpu, radeon, and nouveau.   amdgpu should be around 22M, not 354M, radeon.ko should be just under 4M, not 51M.  and nouveau should be around 6M, not 192M.    I would guess that all other modules are also over-sized.  Did you enable debugging symbols when compiling your kernel? or use some unusual compile options?

Comment: if you didn't compile the kernel yourself, where did you get it from?  check to see if they have an updated kernel-image package.  or stick to stock debian kernels.

Comment: @cas I compiled and installed the kernel myself.

Comment: I suggest you don't do that, then....especially if your reason for installing the new kernel is just that 6.4 is a bigger number than 6.1.   If you don't have an actually good reason to upgrade (i.e. you **need** something it provides or fixes) then don't upgrade.  See [DontBreakDebian - Don't suffer from Shiny New Stuff Syndrome](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_suffer_from_Shiny_New_Stuff_Syndrome)

Comment: @cas Okay, thank you for your suggestion.